# Xcode 5 IOS 7 error: failed to launch '/private/var/mobile/Applications/' -- NotFound

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I am trying to test apps on my IOS device. I have gotten a few to work, however the one I am trying to install now (https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html) is giving me the following error.

I get a popup that says:

> Could not launch “AccelerometerGraph”

and in the console:

> error: failed to launch
>   '/private/var/mobile/Applications/45F20998-B62C-4D0F-B867-9DB4DF15D94B/AccelerometerGraph.app'
>   -- NotFound

I have tried every suggestion in: [Can not launch the app on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010523/can-not-launch-the-app-on-device)

Any other thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

for me restarting device and mac usually fixes this kind of problems

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check to make sure all of the settings in the 'General' section of the app are correct for your device. You could have bumped one of them and not noticed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear `Derived Data` from `'Organizer' -> 'Project' -> ${Your Project}`
2. Go to `'Organizer' -> ${Your Device} -> 'Provisioning Profiles'` and remove (if any) invalid profiles.
3. Disconnect your `device -> Restart XCode -> connect device`.

Answer (score -1):

Connect your device (iPhone) to the Internet (Wi-Fi or 4G).